# Android resource ID lost in ternary operator with methods

Tags: java, android, resources

This is a weird edge case I am experiencing. I am assigning a resource ID for a drawable to a variable through a ternary operator that uses methods (which return the integers representing the resource IDs). Here is an example of the issue I am running into:

```
private int test() {
    return R.drawable.ic_one;
}

public void main() {
    int myIcon = (true) ? test() : R.drawable.ic_two;
    imageView.setImageResource(myIcon);
}
```

In the example above, `setImageResource` won't compile because it wants a resource ID. However, if you change the ternary operator to reference the ID directly, it works:

```
int myIcon = (true) ? R.drawable.ic_one : R.drawable.ic_two;
```

This would indicate that the return value (int) of `test()` was to blame, but using `test()` directly also works:

```
int myIcon = test();
```

Given that both the ternary operator and method return work in isolation, what about combining them makes this fail?

Answer (score 1):

Probably some goofiness in how the build tools are handling the support annotations. Try adding `@DrawableRes` to the return value of `test()`. I think this would be the syntax, though I'm not 100% certain:

```
private @DrawableRes int test() {
    return R.drawable.ic_one;
}
```

Comment: Halfway there! This resolves the compile errors (and the linter underline), however the final app still doesn't display the icons. An oddity in the build tools would sound correct for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try some like:

```
int myIcon = ((true) ? R.drawable.ic_one : R.drawable.ic_two);
```

some times, i dont know why, the compiler get the first argument of ternary like result...

Comment: Tried that one with no luck.

Comment: Man, so I think this is a bug. Dont see other couses.

Comment: I cant use Android SDK now, but i will see this when i can, if havent solved yet.